# Fetching rows from a table in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

views.py:

```
    rows = None
    locname = "select location_name from locations"
    cursor=con.cursor()
    a=cursor.execute(locname) 
    rows=a.fetchall()          

return render(request,'project/output.html',{'rows':rows})
```

output.py:

```
<html>
    <body>
       {{rows}}
    </body> 
</html>
```

When I try to print rows value in output.html,its printing None instead of the value present in rows.Please suggest what is wrong with my code

Comment: You would usually use the ORM, e.g. `rows = Location.objects.all()`, but apart from that your code looks ok. Maybe the problem is in the rest of the view or the urls.

Comment: You need to iterate over this object and access the desired value from it like - for obj in rows: obj.location_name